# Finding the number of terms of binomial expansion $(1+x+x^2)^{20}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-theorem

> In the expansion of $(1+x+x^2)^{20}$, find the number of terms in the binomial expansion.

Let $(1+x)$ be one term and $x^2$ as the second terms

$$\binom {20} {0} C x^{40}(1+x)^0+\binom {20} {1}Cx^{39}(1+x)^1+\dotsb+\binom {20} {20} x^0(1+x)^{20}$$

Number of terms $= 1+2+3+\dotsb +20 = 20\cdot \frac{21}{2}=210$?

But the answer is 41. How? Can anyone explain it to me why I am wrong? And why answer should be 41

This is a gmat exam question.

Comment: The polynomial $(1+x+x^2)^{20}$ is of degree 40.  How many terms can it possibly have?

Comment: `why I am wrong` You are expanding the product, but don't collect the terms in the same power of $x$.

Comment: What is $C$ here ?

Comment: The terms you wrote down can be viewed as binomial-terms, so there are actually $41$ of them.

Comment: The main problem is : what is meant by a BINOMIAL expansion ?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed as the above comment by Xander Henderson explains, the degree of the polynomial is 40, hence it has at most 41 terms. In fact, it has exactly 41 terms as none of the coefficients of $x^i \ : \ i \in \{0, 1, 2, \cdots , 40\}$ are $0$.

In your method, you seemed to have missed that there are 210 terms **before** simplifying the expression, but it would seem that after collecting each term the final answer comes out to be 41.